# (QGIS) How can I join overlapping polygons, retaining each overlapping pairing with proportions?

Tags: qgis

I have two polygon shapefiles--blocks groups (BGs) and neighborhoods. Generally, BGs are smaller than neighborhoods. Sometimes they lie entirely within a neighborhood, but often they overlap two or more.

I can merge these so that the first joining attribute (neighborhood) is retained, but this isn't what I need. How can I join these two files so that the attribute table contains a row for each BG-Neighborhood pairing, with a variable giving the proportion of the BG contained in that neighborhood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that in following image **polygon1** green shapefile is a neighborhood an it is overlapped by blue buffers (blocks groups). By using field calculator determine area for each feature block group; as it can be observed at attributes table.

[image]

Run Intersection tool (Vector -> Geoprocessing tool -> Intersection) for BGs and neighborhood (polygon1) to get it and determine feature area in same way as above case.

[image]

Join to Intersection layer, by id, BGs layer. Result is as follow:

[image]

By using Field calculator determine overlapping percentage as follow:

[image]

Result is:

[image]

and layer must be saved with another name to preserve changes.